# Why can't we use text property to change element?

Tags: javascript

Why we can not use text property to change element, instead we must have to use innerHTML property?

It does not work:

```
h1.text = "The Title";
```

And it works:

```
h1.innerHTML = "The title"; //It's worked;
```

Comment: I recommend learning the basics of javascript and the DOM without any framework (like JQuery).

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaking the native DOM api with the jQuery API.

---

**To set text**

jQuery

```
$elem.text("foo");
```

DOM API

```
elem.textContent = "foo";
```

---

**To set HTML**

jQuery

```
$elem.html("<p>foo</p>");
```

DOM API

```
elem.innerHTML = '<p>foo</p>';
```

---

Using the DOM API, you can also use a `textNode` to add text to an element.

```
var p    = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("foo");
p.appendChild(text);
//=> <p>foo</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. And why I can run: h1.text = "The Title"  in chrome dev, And get a string value.

Comment: @GeXiaoxiong when you do `var a = {}; a.text = "title";` the return value is `"title"`. That doesn't mean Chrome is actually setting the textContent of the `h1` element; that's just the return value of a javascript assignment expression.

Answer (score 0):

**".text"** is not supported in javascript, there is no property in js

and the jQuery library have the funtion called **html(argu)** to operate the innerHTML of javascript

and [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) you can get the basic knowledge about DOM

Answer (score 0):

You will used this `h1.innerHTML = "Hello world!"` if you are using a javascript. Otherwise `$("h1").text("Hello world!");` if you used JQuery.

Comment: jQuery ___is___ JavaScript. And no, `innerHTML` and `.text()` aren't quite comparable like that.

Comment: Sorry. A JQuery library.

Comment: Not quite correct... jQuery is a JavaScript library.